# Solving second-order Taylor series for critical point

Tags: multivariable-calculus, numerical-methods, taylor-expansion, vector-analysis, gradient-descent

My textbook, *Deep Learning* by Goodfellow, Bengio, and Courville, says the following in a section on numerical computation:

> Newton's method is based on using a second-order Taylor series expansion to approximate $f(\mathbf{x})$ near some point $\mathbf{x}^{(0)}$:
>
> $$f(\mathbf{x}) \approx f(\mathbf{x}^{(0)}) + (\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x}^{(0)})^T \nabla_{\mathbf{x}}f(\mathbf{x}^{(0)}) + \dfrac{1}{2}(\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x}^{(0)})^T \mathbf{H}(f)(\mathbf{x}^{(0)})(\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x}^{(0)})$$
>
> If we then solve for the critical point of this function, we obtain
>
> $$\mathbf{x}^* = \mathbf{x}^{(0)} - \mathbf{H}(f)(\mathbf{x}^{(0)})^{-1} \nabla_{\mathbf{x}} f(\mathbf{x}^{(0)})$$

$\mathbf{H}$ is the Hessian.

I was wondering if someone could please take the time to show how it is that we obtain

$$\mathbf{x}^* = \mathbf{x}^{(0)} - \mathbf{H}(f)(\mathbf{x}^{(0)})^{-1} \nabla_{\mathbf{x}} f(\mathbf{x}^{(0)})$$

if we solve for the critical point.

Comment: You understand that $∇_{\bf x}f({\bf x}^*)={\bf 0}$ is the condition for a critical point? Then what you are asking about is just the usual Newton step for a system of equations.

Comment: @LutzL I understand that $\nabla_{\bf x}f({\bf x}^*)={\bf 0}$ is the condition for a critical point, but I'm not familiar with this "Newton step" you mention. Can you please demonstrate how it is used to obtain $\mathbf{x}^* = \mathbf{x}^{(0)} - \mathbf{H}(f)(\mathbf{x}^{(0)})^{-1} \nabla_{\mathbf{x}} f(\mathbf{x}^{(0)})$?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2710463/why-do-we-need-to-find-the-inverse-of-a-hessian-in-second-order-optimization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand\bF{\mathbf{F}}\newcommand\bx{\mathbf{x}}\newcommand\bs{\mathbf{s}}\newcommand\bH{\mathbf{H}}$
For a stationary point you need to solve the system $$∇_\bx f(\bx^*)={\bf 0}.$$

- > The Newton-Kantorovich method for any non-linear system ${\bf F}({\bf x})={\bf 0}$ uses, just as in the scalar case, the linear Taylor expansion $\bF(\bx+\bs)=\bF(\bx)+\bF'(\bx)\bs$ to compute the step update $\bs=-\bF'(\bx)^{-1}\bF(\bx)$ so that finally
  >   $$
  > \bx_{new}=\bx-\bF'(\bx)^{-1}\bF(\bx)
  > $$
  >   is the Newton step. $\bF'(\bx)$ is the Jacobi matrix, also written as $D\bF(\bx)$, $J_{\bF}(\bx)$, etc.

Now $(∇_\bx f)'(\bx)=\bH_f(\bx)$ is the Hessean matrix of $f$ (also written as $∇_\bx^*∇_\bx f$ or simply $f''$) so that for the iteration towards the critical point the Newton step reads as
$$
\bx_{new}=\bx-(∇_\bx f)'(\bx)^{-1}∇_\bx f(\bx)=\bx-\bH_f(\bx)^{-1}∇_\bx f(\bx)
$$

Comment: But how does this resemble the result from the textbook?

Comment: By direct insertion of $\bF=∇_\bx f$. In the book, the result of the Newton step is really only the next, hopefully better, approximation and not the exact location of the critical point. So they should have written better $\bx^*\approx \bx^{(1)}=N(\bx^{(0)})$.

Comment: Your LaTeX is not formatting.

Comment: When I made the comment, the macro definitions of the answer still applied. Strange scoping evolution. Is it readable enough understanding that `\b` stands for "bold"?

Comment: Yes, that’s fine.